# Find child element with specific id value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I want to know, if there is a child div with the id attribute of the current clicked div.

```
$(document).on('click', '.sw-item' , function() {
    if ($("#softwarelist").find("div").attr('id', '' + $(this).attr("id") + '').length = 0) {
        $("#softwarelist").append("<div id='" + $(this).attr("id") + "' class='softwarelist-item'>" + $(this).html() + "</div>");
    }
});
```

When I found a child div in #softwarelist, I dont want to append (add) this to the softwarelist div. The append works, but the if statement is wrong. Someone knows the correct if statement?

Comment: Id should be unique, therefore, you don't need to work hard to find it, just use `$("#id")`

Comment: So you're searching for an element **with the same ID as another element**? That's your issue right there.

Comment: with the same id in another div. Changed the operator == and now it appends ony at the first click.
the (this) element is an other div as the #softwarelist.

Comment: You can't have the same ID in another div, ID's are unique for the entire document

Comment: Anyway, this would do it -> `$("#softwarelist [id='"+this.id+"']")`

Comment: Instead of using id twice which creates invalid html i recommend to use data-product. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it you're setting the `id`. Providing a second parameter to `.attr()` will set instead of get

```
if ($("#softwarelist").find("div").attr('id') == '' + $(this).attr("id") + '') {
```

Comment: this is working, but only for the first element I clicked. When I clicked a second one, I can append the div more than one. So, I need to give the attr id the value $(this).attr("id") - cause this is the id of the clicked element. When it founds the div with the id value, I dont want to add the same div with the same id to the #softwarelist.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the id you're looking for and then turn it into a selector and use `.find()` to see if that selector is found in the `#softwarelist`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.sw-item' , function() {
    if ($("#softwarelist").find("#id" + this.id).length) {
       // child id found
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
$(document).on('click', '.sw-item' , function() {
    if ($("#softwarelist").find("div[id = '" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").length == 0) {
        $("#softwarelist").append("<div id='" + $(this).attr("id") + "' class='softwarelist-item'>" + $(this).html() + "</div>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As user Itay Gal has already pointed out a id should be unique.

I think i understood your requirements now. 
If a user clicks on a product this product should be added to the `softwareList` only once. 
Therefore you would like to test if this particular product is already in the list and add it only if its not already added.

#### HTML with list of products

```
<div id="softwareItems">
<div id="p7" class="sw-item">Windows 7</div>
<div id="p2013" class="sw-item">Visual Studio 2013</div>
<div id="p00" class="sw-item">Beyond Compare</div>
</div>
```

#### The softwarelist

The clicked products from above are added to softwarelist

```
<div id="softwarelist">
     <h3>You picked these items</h3>
</div>
```

To make the code valid html i changed it slightly by using `data-product` as an attribute

```
$(document).on('click', '.sw-item' , function() {               
    var thisID = $(this).attr("id");
    var softwareList = $("#softwarelist");
    var elementsFound = softwareList.find("div[data-product='"+thisID +"']");

    if (elementsFound.length == 0) {
         softwareList.append("<div data-product='" +thisID + "'>"  
                                 + $(this).html()  
                           + "</div>");
    }    
});
```

This way you can test if the product is already in the softwarelist without creating invalid html by using the id twice.